# Create absolutely positioned pseudo element anchored to right side of screen rather than parent container

Tags: css

I have a container with a percentage width of `90%` and a max-width of `1000px`. The container is divided into 3rds with 2 columns. For the right column I want to have a pseudo element to act as a background but I want the background to extend all the way to the right edge of the screen rather than the right edge of the container. I feel like this can be accomplished with `calc()` somehow but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  width:90%;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.left-column, .right-column {
  min-height:200px;
  position:relative;
}

.left-column {
  width:calc(100% / 3 * 2);
  background-color:gray;
}

.right-column {
  width:calc(100% / 3);
  align-self:flex-start;
  color:#fff;
}
  .right-column:after {
    display:block;
    content:"";
    /* 1/3 container width plus half of the width of the gutter */
    width:calc(100vw / 3 + 5%);
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    /* half of the width of the gutter */
    right:-5%;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed libero nisl, suscipit vel neque eget, luctus ultrices nisl. Fusce non scelerisque magna, quis efficitur nunc. Phasellus vitae faucibus urna. Etiam semper nec ipsum a laoreet. Curabitur eget facilisis risus. Sed at metus ac risus tristique suscipit vitae vel elit. Donec sollicitudin nisi sed sem feugiat pellentesque. Morbi diam urna, posuere id erat quis, bibendum interdum lorem. Sed iaculis, erat eu sagittis lacinia, purus nisl suscipit diam, condimentum tempus neque nibh interdum massa. Suspendisse luctus eget neque sed suscipit. Donec nulla mauris, posuere sit amet velit vel, ullamcorper lobortis nunc. Duis ut pulvinar ipsum. Aenean interdum elementum aliquam. Nulla facilisi.

In egestas, turpis ut sollicitudin laoreet, dolor metus dictum enim, vel laoreet quam urna ac lacus. Nam iaculis felis in malesuada auctor. Nam suscipit pulvinar ipsum. Praesent convallis bibendum felis nec accumsan. Nulla dapibus lorem tortor, ut dapibus odio elementum sed. Nam tempor condimentum nibh. Fusce porta suscipit nisi vitae bibendum. Maecenas euismod ut nisl et imperdiet. Mauris commodo velit id dapibus congue. Vivamus sagittis ante quis augue vestibulum, in vulputate tortor cursus. Praesent congue, elit nec semper finibus, dui metus viverra massa, quis euismod nunc urna consequat dui.</div>
  <div class="right-column">Blue should extend to the edge of the screen</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with following, based on would I could understand.

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/xxyrWQL)

**Give right col relative position**

```
.right-column {
  /* ... */
  position: relative;
}
```

**Give the pseudo left 0 and width 100vw**

With the parent relative, now you have a reference to the left-side of the right-col. Using left 0 and width 100vw, now the blue grows sideways and safely bleeds out of the viewport. Since it's position absolute, it won't invoke any overflow scrolling. To be extra safe, you can put an `overflow-x:hidden` on your body (good practice anyhow).

```
 .right-column:after {
    /* ... */
    width:100vw;
    left: 0;
  }
```